# How can I debug CarrierWave silently failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm attempting to use CarrierWave in a rails 4.0 / ruby 2.0 app, but have no success doing any image manipulation. I can upload full-size images no problem, but even trying to resize causes a silent failure.

For example, `process :resize_to_fill => [100,100]` is enough to keep it from working. As expected, trying to make a thumbnail won't work either.

I've tried RMagick and MiniMagic, but neither make a difference. The only clues I can give is that my model instance shows `image` to be populated, but when using `process`, it's *nil* and the `@widget.save` fails.

It appears the original and thumbnail are saving full-resolution in the tmp directory, but that's about as far as it gets.

ImageMagick is up to date via MacPorts.

Any ideas?

Comment: It turns out I had a much older active version of ImageMagick installed via MacPorts (though other versions were listed), and while it worked on the CLI, it wasn't playing nicely with MiniMagick or RMagick. Uninstall/clean/reinstall seemed to fix it

Comment: http://benw.me/posts/carrierwave-failing-silently/ helped me out